# Dockerize a Maven Project with a Laravel project

Tags: java, php, docker, maven

I am having issues developing a project. This project consists of a Laravel project which is my API REST. Some of the methods call a Java project. So, basically, I have a Laravel project which interacts with a Java (maven) project.

All of this is the back-end of my app, so I decided to group all of this with docker. Basically, I have three containers:

- Nginx
- MySQL
- PHP

The Php container is built by a Dockerfile. In this Dockerfile y run the commands for installing R software and Composer (for the Laravel project). But also I need to include Maven.

I have read in many pages the best to do this is using multi-stage Dockerfile, and that's exactly what I am trying, but I can't get it working ...

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm
USER root
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y git && \
    apt-get -y install software-properties-common

RUN wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/apache-maven-3.3.9.tar.gz http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz
RUN tar xzf /tmp/apache-maven-3.3.9.tar.gz -C /opt/
RUN ln -s /opt/apache-maven-3.3.9 /opt/maven
RUN ln -s /opt/maven/bin/mvn /usr/local/bin
RUN rm -f /tmp/apache-maven-3.3.9.tar.gz
ENV MAVEN_HOME /opt/maven

RUN apt install -y r-base

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www/html

USER www-data:www-data

FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./machine-learning/RecommendationSystem/pom.xml .
RUN mvn -B -f ./pom.xml -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-docker.xml dependency:go-offline
COPY ./machine-learning/RecommendationSystem/ .
RUN mvn -B -f ./pom.xml -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-docker.xml package
```

It actually does everything, but the container gives me a Exit 1.

Just in case someone thinks this is necessary, here is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'xxx'
      MYSQL_USER: 'xxx'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'xxx'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'xxx'
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

Hope someone can help me :( If you need more info or something is not explained correctly, let me know and I'll try to do my best.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: How are you interacting with the Java process?  (Can it be over HTTP, in a separate container?)  The key with a multi-stage build is that the last stage needs to be the one actually containing your application (so `FROM php` needs to be last, if the main application is Laravel).  It's hard to copy the actual software out of some other image, rather than use it as a supporting build tool, though; you may need to `apt-get install` a JVM and Maven here.

Comment: `I decided to group all of this with docker` <= which is precisely what you don't want to do when trying to deal with micro-services. Make a container for each of laravel and java service.

Comment: Hi David, I am interacting with Java via bash commands. If I do put the php image the last one do I have guaranteed that "mvn" command will be available in the container?

Comment: Hi Zeitounator, might I do a Laravel container and Java container and make them use the same network? I need to execute "mvn" commands from php container because the Laravel project needs to execute the java code via bash